# How to remove a filter from spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In `Spring Security 4.0` there is so called `Default Login Page` which looks like the following:

[image]

Dug a bit into the source code I found the Filter 
[org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/ui/DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java)

which renders that login page. Actually, it has     `private String generateLoginPageHtml(HttpServletRequest request, boolean loginError, boolean logoutSuccess)` method, which contains the following code snippet:

```
if (formLoginEnabled) {
    sb.append("<h3>Login with Username and Password</h3>");
    sb.append("<form name='f' action='").append(request.getContextPath()).append(authenticationUrl).append("' method='POST'>\n");
    sb.append(" <table>\n");
    sb.append("    <tr><td>User:</td><td><input type='text' name='");
    sb.append(usernameParameter).append("' value='").append("'></td></tr>\n");
    sb.append("    <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='").append(passwordParameter).append("'/></td></tr>\n");

    if (rememberMeParameter != null) {
        sb.append("    <tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='").append(rememberMeParameter).append("'/></td><td>Remember me on this computer.</td></tr>\n");
    }

    sb.append("    <tr><td colspan='2'><input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Login\"/></td></tr>\n");
    renderHiddenInputs(sb, request);
    sb.append("  </table>\n");
    sb.append("</form>");
}
```

The issue is I want to remove that filter from the filter chain in order to customize my login page, located by the `http://my-domain/login` url. Is it possible?

My security-config:

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" 
                    access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" 
                default-target-url="/admin" 
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" 
                username-parameter="user"
                password-parameter="password" 
                login-processing-url="/login"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" logout-url="/logout" />
</http>
```

Comment: Just set the login page.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I know that if I set the login page differs from `/login` the filter won't be applied. But is it possible to not apply the Filter with `/login`

Answer (score 6):

Why are you "digging into the source" rather than the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.x/guides/form.html), it quite clearly covers this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login");
}
```

The default login page is only generated if you have no login page set.

If you examine the [source code of `AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-javaconfig/blob/master/spring-security-javaconfig/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.java) you will see:

```
protected T loginPage(String loginPage) {
    this.loginPage = loginPage;
    this.authenticationEntryPoint = new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(loginPage);
    this.customLoginPage = true;
    return getSelf();
}
```

If you then look at the [source code of `FormLoginConfigurer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-javaconfig/blob/master/spring-security-javaconfig/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/FormLoginConfigurer.java):

```
private void initDefaultLoginFilter(H http) {
    DefaultLoginPageViewFilter loginPageGeneratingFilter = http.getSharedObject(DefaultLoginPageViewFilter.class);
    if(loginPageGeneratingFilter != null && !isCustomLoginPage()) {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

So you see, calling `loginPage` sets `customLoginPage = true`. This disables the
`DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter`.

Comment: Well, it will only work if I set up the `loginPage` differs from `/login`.

Comment: @St.Antario not true.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried it million times and make sure that it's true. Have you tried it in spring security 4.0?

Comment: I added the configuration I'm using, could you look at it?

Comment: @St.Antario look at the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-javaconfig/blob/master/spring-security-javaconfig/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.java). Setting `loginPage` sets `customLoginPage = true` which disables the filter.

Comment: @St.Antario I added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: your documentation link is broken.

Comment: Also found it a bit humorous that you asked him why he was "digging into the source" and then your answer suggests 2 classes for him to dig into the source of ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following tags to configure it viz.

```
<sec:form-login login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/home.html" always-use-default-target="true"/>
```

Similar way log out  as well

```
<sec:logout logout-url="/logoutnow.html" logout-success-url="/logout.html"/>
```

Read documentation for further information.

Answer (score 0):

issue [SEC-2919](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2919) covers this ticket, try to upgrade to 4.0.1

> spring-issuemaster commented on Apr 28, 2015
>   Rick UPADHYAY (Migrated from SEC-2949) said:
>
> i created a simple spring mvc project and added a custom login page. The custom login works fine with 3.2.7 but the same custom login does not work when i upgrade to 4.0.0.Release.
>
> spring-issuemaster commented on Apr 28, 2015
>   Rob Winch said:
>
> Can you elaborate on what you mean by "does not work"?
>
> Did you try upgrading to 4.0.1 to ensure this isn't a duplicate of SEC-2919? Did you ensure to use the migration guides?
>
> spring-issuemaster commented on Apr 28, 2015
>   Rick UPADHYAY said:
>
> Thanks for quick response. upgrading to 4.0.1 has solved my issues. SEC-2919 was my issue. Sorry should have search for existing JIRA issues first.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue. I had to configure spring security with an xml and not with an annotated file. My solution was to replace

```
form-login login-page="/login
```

by

```
form-login login-page="/doLogin"
```